# How to get split data input from the user in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I want to get "3 4 5 7 4 3 2" user input and save it in a list. I tried this code

```
lst = []

for i in range(0, 7): 
    lst = input().split()

#print(lst.sort())
```

But it's gives me a error

```
File "Solution.py", line 4, in <module>
    lst = input().split()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

How should i resolve this error?

Comment: lst = sorted([input() for i in range(0, 7)])

Comment: or if it should be 1 input,  lst = sorted(input().split())

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code to get all the inputs in the list

```
lst = []

for i in range(0, 7): 
    lst.append(input())
```

this code will append each value from the user input to the lst list as a single item.